# Why can't I interrupt IO operations on linux?

Tags: linux, io

I tried to abort mkfs.ntfs applied on USB drive (forgot the Quck format flag) and then another big disk IO operation (using dd). They both took more than several minutes to abort, so I just rebooted, because it was much faster to do than to convince the OS I really want to cancel and don't care about the media state. 
Why is it the case on Linux, why does kill -9  doesn't abort the operation instantaneously or rather fast enough for a human being (something around a pair of seconds at most)?
A pair of seconds is nearly an eternity for a computer to stop a DMA, why does it take so long and do you know if I can tweak some setting to make it faster?

Edit:
This happens on any Kernel in the last 10 years I use Linux. I always hoped the situation would improve but it didn't. The last try yesterday the Kernel had version 4.17. I am using Arch Linux.

Comment: https://lwn.net/Articles/288056/ is some relevant background. see also https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/499d05ecf990 . did you try `kill -9` ?  maybe TASK_KILLABLE only reacts to SIGKILL, i am not sure.

Comment: @sourcejedi I think the result has been in the question. They didn't terminate quickly.

Comment: oops, good point!  You could see roughly which function in the kernel the process is blocking inside. You can use `sudo cat /proc/$(pidof dd)/stack`. https://ops.tips/blog/using-procfs-to-get-process-stack-trace/ , There is also `echo w | sudo tee /proc/sysrq-trigger`, I think it will stack-trace all tasks which are blocked on IO.